# Adding a unique constraint for a relationship 2 degrees away

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Consider this database with 4 tables (primary-keys in asterisks):

```
Products( *ProductId*, SkuText, ... )
ProductRevisions( ProductId, *RevisionId*, ... )
Orders( *OrderId*, ... )
OrderItems( *OrderId*, *ProductRevisionId*, Quantity, ... )
```

The idea being that a Product SKU can have multiple revisions (e.g. a 2016 version of a product compared to its 2015 version). The business rules are such that an `Order` for a `Product` can only have a single `ProductRevision`, e.g. an order cannot request both the 2014 and 2016 versions of the same product, they can only have the 2014 **or** 2016 version.

Ordinarily this wouldn't be a problem: the `OrderItems` table would have a `ProductId` column with a `UNIQUE` constraint on `OrderId` and `ProductId`. However because `OrderItems`'s references `ProductRevisionId` (so the reference to the `ProductId` is indirect) it means a simple `UNIQUE` constraint fails and the schema would accept the following data, even though it is invalid as-per the business rules:

```
Products
ProductId, SkuText
        1, 'Kingston USB Stick'

ProductRevisions
ProductId, RevisionId, ...
        1,          1, '2014 model'
        1,          2, '2016 model'

Orders
OrderId
        1

OrderItems
OrderId, ProductRevisionId, Quantity
      1,                 1,      100
      1,                 2,       50 -- Invalid data! Two revisions of the same Product should not be in the same order.
```

What I need is something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE OrderItems
    ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE ( OrderId, SELECT ProductId FROM ProductRevisions WHERE RevisionId = OrderItems.ProductRevisionId )
```

I don't want to denormalize my `OrderItems` table by adding an explicit `ProductId` column because that adds a potential point of failure if the parent/child relationship between a given `ProductId` and `ProductRevisionId` were to change then the data becomes invalid.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a comment, but it is too long.

One option is to create a trigger.  This allows you to validate the data using any rules that you want.  However, triggers are cumbersome and unnecessary.

Another option is essentially what you say:  include both `Product` and `ProductRevision` in `OrderLines`.  However, this doesn't quite solve the problem.  You need to ensure that the product actually matches the product on the revision.

I am thinking that the best option might be to have a `Revision` column in `ProductRevisions`.  So, this table would have:

- `ProductRevisionId` -- primary key for the table
- `ProductId`
- `RevisionId`
- unique constraint on `(ProductId, RevisionId)`

The foreign key constraint in `OrderLines` can then have two columns in it -- `(ProductId, RevisionId)`.  Then a unique constraint on `(OrderId, ProductId)` ensures only one revision.

The downside to this method is that a product can only appear on only one line in each order.  However, you don't need triggers.

Comment: "The downside to this method is that a product can only appear on only one line in each order. "  - that's not a downside, that's exactly what I'm after :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an indexed view to enforce the constraint. In your case, it'd be something like:

```
create view [OrderItemProductRevisions]
with schemabinding
as
   select oi.OrderID, pr.ProductID
   from dbo.OrderItems as oi
   join dbo.ProductRevisions as pr
      on oi.ProductRevisionID = pr.ProductRevisionID
go
create unique clustered index [CUIX_OrderItemProductRevisions]
   on [OrderItemProductRevisions] (OrderID, ProductID)
go
```

Now, if you try to add two revisions of the same product to the same order, you should violate the unique index on the view and it will be disallowed.

Comment: Wouldn't the index only be updated when the view is queried next, or are all views and view indexes evaluated whenever a table has data updated?

Comment: Indexed view are maintained in the same transaction as the data manipulation that caused the view results to change.